# How do I pretend that my high resolution spectrometer only has low resolution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy

I have a spectrometer with resolution high enough to recognize the fine structure in alkali metal. Now if I add these two peaks together and ignore the non-resonance part between them, what do I get? Is it the right way to pretend that my high resolution spectrometer only has low resolution?

Comment: By "pretend" you mean reproduce exactly the measurement result from a lower resolution spectrometer?

Comment: One could always convolute the data with a lower resolution function.

Comment: I'm curious why you would be interested in doing such a thing, though that may just be my inexperience talking :)

Comment: @JonCuster *Convolve*

Comment: @DoktorJ A common case is when you have the (high resolution) output of a simulation that you want to examine under multiple potential experimental design assumptions. That is, you do this kind of thing during the design phase of experimental physics.

Comment: @DoktorJ modelling whether a low-resolution measurement can give sufficient information for an experiment based on very good data is useful with FTIR, where there's a trade-off between resolution and time (and signal-to-noise).  You may not simply be able to wait longer if you can't treat you sample as constant.  Or as dmckee says, getting simulation data into an experimental scale, as I did in my thesis: thermal simulations have higher resolution than Raman thermography, so convolution is how you compare simulation to experiment (in 3D)

Comment: @BlackThorn - Mea culpa, probably because the result is a convolution, it was not uncommon for 'convolute' to be used colloquially several decades ago.

Comment: Thank you all very much. I want to reduce the resolution of my spectrometer because I'm doing research in which I try to control  population in different excited states in molecule and atom using strong ultra-short laser pulse, i.e. try to control absorption line shape. Yesterday, I don't know whether the result I've got about rubidium atom origins from coupling of states in fine structure or from Rabi oscillation or from AC stark effect,  so I want to treat the fine structure as an undistinguished line so that I can analyze the phenomenon more deeply.

Comment: @stafusa At first yes. When I think over it again and again, I found I want more. I found I don't have a kind of ability that analyze the population of excited states clearly through the absorption line shape because my lack of some important knowledge.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The way to artificially decrease the resolution of your spectrum is to convolve it with a broadening function. Typically you'd use a gaussian.

Suppose your spectrum is the function $F(\lambda)$ i.e. the function $F(\lambda)$ gives the intensity measured at the wavelength $\lambda$. Take the function $g$ given by:

$$ g(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)} $$

and calculate the new function:

$$ F'(\lambda) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x)g(\lambda - x) dx $$

This is called the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of $F$ with $g$, and the effect is to smooth out the function $F$ and decrease the resolution. The parameter $\sigma$ determines the degree of smoothing. The larger the value of $\sigma$ the greater will be the smoothing. You will need to experiment to get the amount of smoothing you want.

This may seem a bit odd, but this is roughly what happens in real life. If $F$ is the perfect spectrum and $g$ describes the resolution of your spectrometer then the convolution of $F$ and $g$ is the measurement that you will get.

Finally, the odd prefactor of $1/\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}$ is just a normalising factor. It keeps the overall intensity of your smoothed spectrum constant.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I basically understand your answer but still don't understand the effect of non-resonance part if the resolution is really high, could you please explain it?

Comment: @Bettertomo I'm not sure what you are asking. The effect of the smoothing is to spread out two closely spaced lines so they appear as a single broad line.

Comment: If the resolution of my spectrometer is really high, then there is a large gap between the distinguished line. Does this gap important?

Comment: Uh, I suddenly don't understand my own question, forgive me!

Comment: Is the σ here the same as the σ used when reporting measurement uncertainty?

Comment: Convolving with a Gaussian will be essentially a form of low-pass filtering. From there, you could (if you wanted) down-sample to actually get lower resolution data. This combination of low-pass filtering followed by down-sampling is called [decimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(signal_processing)). The (basics of the) theory of low-pass filtering and decimation may be worth looking at to, e.g., avoid aliasing by not low-pass filtering aggressively enough (not an issue if you don't down-sample).

Comment: A cruder but simpler approach (often used for noddling around analyses) is to simple re-bin the histogram into fewer bins.

Comment: Computationally, you'd take your data and make it discrete (in magnitude and frequency) at sufficient resolution.  Then you'd apply a FFT (fast fourier transform), bandlimit, and inverse-FFT.  Or, if you are married to a guassian, you apply a FFT, pointwise multiply with guassian kernel, then inverse-FFT.  Actually convolving is computationally expensive!  Or you'd throw the signal and the kernel at an engine that (under the hood) does the FFT, pointwise multiplication, inverse-FFT without telling you.

Comment: In practice rather than $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ you can pick realistic limits like  $\int_{-4\sigma}^{4\sigma}$